# How to cancel an order when a payment gateway page timesout in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

i have integrated a 3rd party payment gateway into magento. It handels a successful transaction or a failed transaction perfectly.

But what if when the user is at the payment gateway page and it times out or when at the payment gateway page the user closes the page and returns back to the site later or user simply hits the back button,

- how do i cancel the order then?
- Should i use some observer to do this?
- If so could you suggest to which events do i need to fire the observer?

the issue i am facing is that when a user is redirected to a payment gateway and he/she hits the back button and comes back to the site, the order is still created, which ideally should have been canceled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation methods should not be session aware and should process any feedback (and validate before you process) in any case. You also need a monitoring service that times out orders without a response after some time if you need them to be disabled in timely fashion.

However if user hits back button there is really nothing you can do as the feedback from payment gateway never gets sent on user action. I know some payment gateways issue automatic post from the server no matter what you have to investigate if this can be also possible with your payment gateway.

Comment: Should my validations be through javascript or perform the validation in a observer? Also could you suggest which event would be the best in my scenario? Would `sales_order_place_after` be the ideal event?

Comment: Also could you please give an example of a monitoring service that best fits my needs. Thanks.

Comment: you can use magento crontab jobs to set up monitoring for your extension. if you are talking about payment gateway response validation (and users clicking back)  then you mean that users are leaving your site for payment placement?

Comment: Yes, the issue i am facing is that when a user is redirected to a payment gateway and he/she hits the back button and comes back to the site, the order is still created, which ideally should have been canceled. I want to fire a observer when ever a order is created and if the order is not in processing state after about 15 min (say for a time out)  i want to cancel the order. But not sure how to handle the scenario when the user hits the back button when at the payment gateway page.

Comment: But i want to perform the check only when a order is created. Can a cron be triggered for such an event? Can you please provide a snippet of code for the magento cron job?

Comment: cron job is a timely task that is executed over and over in a certain scheduled time interval. you have to implement the check that cancels orders that mach your criteria